# Communicate with USB port on WIndows 7 in C

Tags: c, usb, communication

I need to make a C program that sends data to an USB port so that the PC can communicate with an external device. However, I have never done this and I have been Google:ing like crazy but I find it hard to understand the code samples that are out there. I have taken a look at the 
tcl/tk library and have heard that it should work.

- Is that the easiest library to use for Windows 7 for communicating
  with USB?
- Do you know any other libraries that are easier to use?
- Do you know any good tutorials or examples for beginners?
- Can any of you who have experience with this give me an example code of how to connect to a
  USB port and send data to it?

Comment: I have a coworker that has had success doing this with the libusb library.

Answer (score 0):

It's a possibility that your device is using an FTDI USB-to-serial chip (or similar), which means that although it has a USB front end, the device is actually speaking in serial/ttl. If this is the case you could talk to your device using serial APIs instead of USB. You would have to verify that this is the case though, but it is probably worth verifying as it could make your life a heck of a lot easier if the above is true.

As for actually programming with USB, the only thing I'm aware of is what mah mentioned - libusb.

Cheers.